Why is matroid R10 non-graphic
I have a question about a non-graphic matroid $R_{10}$. I have this standard representation:
$R_{10}$ =
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
I know that this matroid is not graphic, but I am not able to prove it somehow. Do I have to use one of the algorithms which for me are kind of hard to grasp or is there an easier way, such like showing this matroid has some non-graphic matroid as a minor?

The forbidden minors for binary matroids that are graphic are the duals of the graphic matroids for $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$.

To expand a little on Randy Marsh's comment, any matroid $M$ with a $M^*(K_{5})$ or a $M^*(K_{3,3})$ minor is non-graphic. Now, every single element contraction of $R_{10}$ is isomorphic to $M^*(K_{3,3})$, which implies $R_{10}$ is not graphic.
